# CSVwriter writerall changes date format of resultset with java

Tags: java, opencsv

I am exporting the table in sql server to CSV file with csvwriter (opencsv),Date format is changed in csv file. actual date format in sql server  is  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS but it converts to 19-Sep-2014 09:13:00.I am using Ubuntu os.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but it looks like you can set the format CSVWriter will use:

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = ..
ResultSetHelperService resultSetHelperService= new ResultSetHelperService();
resultSetHelperService.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
resultSetHelperService.setDateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS");
csvWriter.setResultService(resultSetHelperService);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query make it so that the date returned from the sql query is in a format you like. For example:

```
 SELECT lastName, DATE_FORMAT(someDate,'%Y-%m-%d %T') AS columnName from mytable
```

This way when it is returned to CSV writer it will be in a format of your choice. You can then use the query to loop through and write.

```
        String[] columns = {"lastName","columnName"};

        writer.writeNext(columns);

        while(rs.next()){

            String[] values = {
                    rs.getString("lastName"),
                    rs.getString("columnName")
                    };

             writer.writeNext(values);
        }
```

Comment: I am dumping the table to csv (select * operation)                                  
writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-16"),CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);                                          
 writer.writeAll(rset, false);

Comment: Okay, updated my answer. Please check. The example I have given worked fine with MySQL. You need a similar thing I believe.

Comment: I am converting like CONVERT(DATETIME, tblDoctor.[PasscodeDate], 105) AS Doctor_PasscodeDate . Even though  i am getting same thing. when i print resultset i am getting correct format.but when i write to file with writeall(rset ) method i am getting this issue. it might be csvwriter issue. any way thanks for help

Comment: In this i dont know col names (lastname,firstname),the query which i am getting from configuration file, and giving to execute statement and dump to csv file. we have no of select queries in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Format your query like this:

```
select ''||to_date(your_date_field, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from your_table
```

Adding an empty string to the selected date field made the CSVWriter treat it as string and write it as is.